# How do you perform a chronological sort after another sort in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following documents in elasticsearch. `value` is an integer and `date` is a datetime object:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "source": {
        "date": "2018-05-01 18:00:00"
        "value": 10,
    }
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "source": {
        "date": "2018-07-03 13:00:00"
        "value": 500,
    }
},
{
    "_id": 3,
    "source": {
        "date": "2018-10-05 20:00:00"
        "value": 80,
    }
},
```

If I want to get the top 2 with the highest value sorted by date, the expected output is:

```
{
    "_id": 2,
    "source": {
        "date": "2018-07-03 13:00:00"
        "value": 500,
    }
},
{
    "_id": 3,
    "source": {
        "date": "2018-10-05 20:00:00"
        "value": 80,
    }
},
```

I have been able to sort either one on their own but they don't work together. Here's my sort query:

```
"sort": [
    {"value": {"order": "desc"}},
    {"date": {"order": "asc"}}
]
```

The above query will sort the documents in descending order properly by value but will ignore chronological sort. Is it even possible to do that kind of double sorting in elasticsearch 2.x?

Comment: In latest you can

Answer (score 0):

Multilevel sorting is possible in 2.x, you are doing it properly. I guess you were expecting a different behavior maybe?

In the [official guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/_sorting.html#_multilevel_sorting) there is a good explanation about how it works:

> Order is important. Results are sorted by the first criterion first.
>   Only results whose first sort value is identical will then be sorted
>   by the second criterion, and so on.